# Trim table of text and store values as variables

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, sh

I am trying to write a script that can be run on my FreeNas (FreeBSD) box, that connects to an ESXi host via SSH and gracefully shuts down VMs. What I need to run for a list of VM IDs is:

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/power.shutdown VMID
```

Am after some assistance in filtering the output of the commands used to retrieve the IDs, and then passing it to the shutdown command.

The command to retrieve all VMs is:

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms
```

It outputs data like this:

```
Vmid     Name                          File                             Guest OS          Version   Annotation
12     Eds-LINUX   [Eds-FS-Datastore-1] Eds-LINUX/Eds-LINUX.vmx   ubuntu64Guest           vmx-13
13     Eds-RT      [Eds-FS-Datastore-1] Eds-RT/Eds-RT.vmx         freebsd64Guest          vmx-13
14     Eds-DC      [Eds-FS-Datastore-1] Eds-DC/Eds-DC.vmx         windows9Server64Guest   vmx-13
15     Eds-STEAM   [Eds-FS-Datastore-1] Eds-STEAM/Eds-STEAM.vmx   windows9_64Guest        vmx-13
16     Eds-DL      [Eds-FS-Datastore-1] Eds-DL/Eds-DL.vmx         windows9Server64Guest   vmx-13
17     Eds-RD      [Eds-FS-Datastore-1] Eds-RD/Eds-RD.vmx         windows9Server64Guest   vmx-13
18     Eds-PLEX    [Eds-FS-Datastore-1] Eds-PLEX/Eds-PLEX.vmx     windows9Server64Guest   vmx-13
19     Eds-MC      [Eds-FS-Datastore-1] Eds-MC/Eds-MC.vmx         windows9Server64Guest   vmx-13
2      Eds-FS      [Eds-ESXi-Datastore-1] Eds-FS/Eds-FS.vmx       freebsd64Guest          vmx-13
```

I have determined I can use a pipe into sed, to delete the first line, using:

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | sed '1d'
```

I am then able to retrieve the ID of the VM I want to filter out, by using:

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | awk '/Eds-FS.vmx/{print$1}'
```

This gives me the ID of 2. I am unclear however, how to store this in a variable for later use.

I need to know of a way to select just the first column from this data, and for each ID in the list, put it in an array. I then need to loop through the array and for each ID, run the below to get the power state of the VM:

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/power.getstate VMID
```

This outputs data like this, with a status of either power on or off:

```
Retrieved runtime info
Powered on
```

For each one that is found to be powered on, I need to store the VM ID in a second array to later pass to the shutdown command, except for where the ID is equal to that of the VM I want to power off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list IDs from first column use `awk` like this:

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | awk 'NR>1{print $1}'
```

To store IDs in a shell array use:

```
readarray -t arr < <(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | awk 'NR>1{print $1}')
```

To loop through array and run another command:

```
for id in "${arr[@]}"; do
   vim-cmd vmsvc/power.getstate "$id"
done
```

To store one particular id use command substitution:

```
vmid1=$(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | awk '/Eds-FS\.vmx/{print$1}')
```

Comment: Thanks. When doing the readarray, I get a syntax error "unexpected redirection"?

Comment: I see. Any thoughts on another way to create an array on ESXi?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to anubhava who gave me enough assistance to get something working (although probably not following standards or best practices)

I have this script saved on my ESXi host, which I connect to with SSH and trigger a run of:

```
freenasid=`vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | sed '1d' | awk '/Eds-FS.vmx/{print$1}'`
vmids=`vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | sed '1d' | awk '{print$1}'`
for vmid in $vmids
do
if [ $vmid != $freenasid ]
then
powerstate=`vim-cmd vmsvc/power.getstate $vmid | sed '1d'`
if [ "$powerstate" = "Powered on" ]
then
onvmids="$onvmids $vmid"
fi
fi
done
for vmid in $onvmids
do
vim-cmd vmsvc/power.shutdown $vmid
done
exit 0
```

This correctly shutsdown all running VMs.